# How to make only certain ListBox items not selectable?

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox, msdn

The ListBox window is created like this:

```
hList = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE ,"LISTBOX",NULL,
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | ES_CENTER |WS_HSCROLL|WS_VSCROLL,
    20, 55, 200, 120,hWindow, (HMENU)ID_LIST, hInstance, 0);
```

It has properties which can be defined, like `WS_VISIBLE` and so on, one of which is `LBS_NOSEL` to remove selection or focusing on an item in the list, but this apply to all the items in the list, so either all can be seleted when `LBS_NOSEL` is not added just like the  above code, or when provided all items cannot be selected.

What I want is: only certain items not to be selected. How do I achieve that?

I add items to the ListBox with `SendMessage` like this:

```
SendMessage(hList, LB_ADDSTRING , 0, (LPARAM)"my text goes here");
```

Comment: A list box control has no provisions for this. You would need to create a [list view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-control-reference) control instead and respond to the [`LVN_ITEMCHANGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvn-itemchanging) notification.

Comment: However, a ListBox does have a LBN_SELCHANGE notification. Although it is triggered after an item is selected, it can check if the current selected item(s) should be unselected and then actually unselect it/them if needed

Comment: The point of this (non selectable item) is to be used as a title to some subitems underneath it, so the title itself should not be selectable. it could be more than one main item in the list with subitems.

Comment: Have a look at the [`CMFCPropertyGridCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcpropertygridctrl-class) class implementation for inspiration on how to implement this.

Comment: Not MFC  but Win32-API

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you to *use* MFC. I was introducing you to an implementation solving your specific issue (an implementation that *is* interfacing with the native Win32 API).

Comment: Another way is to subclass the control and block the interactions that can cause those items to be selected (e.g. block `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` if the mouse is over a special item, etc.)

Comment: It is also possible using different listboxes each with own items , The title could be in the title bar by using WS_CAPTION style.

Comment: Controls are child windows (`WS_CHILD`). They do not have a caption bar.

Comment: If you add WS_CAPTION to the above ListBox  and change NULL to any Text , it will appear in a Title Bar , but I don't like this solution.

Comment: For general purpose, it's unnecessary to disable item selection. Or at least, you can write your implementation through subclassing, the owner-drawn feature, etc.